# Laptop HP Pavillon dv5000 - Audio device not found fresh Windows 8.1 even after installing drivers

Tags: audio, drivers

Until a couple of days ago, my laptop (with Windows 7 Ultimate) worked perfectly including the audio system with any program (music, video, Skype etc..).
After making a full fresh Windows 8.1 installation there was no possible way to have the audio back.

I used many different drivers, updates, manufacturer drivers, other Windows versions but it still will not work. No matter which driver I use, I get the following message: "Windows did not find any media device". However, in the Device Manager, the audio device has a question mark next to it.

Does any one have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: It's good evening for me.

Comment: Have tried troubleshooting the device? It would give some useful information.

Comment: It's possible that Win 8.1 doesn't support this specific driver. I've seen that happen several times after an update, especially with a computer as old as yours. I'll tell you what I tell everyone. You should always BACKUP your drivers before changing the OS. It's an incredibly easy preventative measure and the alternative is substantially harder/more time consuming. Use a program Double Driver in the future to backup drivers. Try using PCI-Z to search for other or at least post the results of PCI-Z. Also, which model is your computer? DV5000 CTO, DV5000t CTO, DV5000ea?

Comment: P.S. Go here: http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-dv5000-Notebook-PC-series/499885/model/499886#Z7_3054ICK0KGTE30AQO5O3KA30R1

Download the driver titled: "Conexant High Definition Audio Driver" and make sure to "Run in Compatibility Mode" as Win XP. (`Right Click > Properties > Compatibility Tab > Check` "Run this program in compatibility for: Win XP" )